# Lagrange multiplier plus or minus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I am working through different tutorials about Lagrange multiplier and came upon a problem. It seems like that there's different ways to solve.

You have a given equation $f(x,y)$ and a constraint $g(x,y)$.

---

A few tutorials then start to set the derivatives respect to $x$ and $y$ of $\lambda\,g(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$ equal to each other and start solving for variables:

$$f(x,y)= \lambda\,g(x,y) \tag{1}$$

or use a form of

$$F(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)  - \lambda \,g(x,y)\tag2$$

which is basically the same since you can subtract the right hand side of $(1)$ and derive $(2)$.

---

Other tutorials use a form of

$$F(x,y,\lambda)= f(x,y) + \lambda\,g(x,y)\tag3$$

---

So the main difference is the minus and the plus in their form and I am not sure which one to use. I have found multiple examples for both, so it's not a single mistake by one of the tutors.

So which one is the correct one: $(2)$ or $(3)$?

<sub>sources for $(1)$, $(2)$: [A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry9cgNx1QV8), [B](https://youtu.be/B7jYcrokjS4?t=250)</sub>

<sub>sources for $(3)$: [C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eREvLgRJWrE), [D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeTtNEAXHZs)</sub>

Comment: See also this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155842/lagrange-multiplier-sign-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with Lagrange multipliers, always keep this in mind: the value of $\lambda$ doesn't matter. This is so because working with the constrains $g(x,y)=1$, $3g(g,y)=3$ or $-\pi g(x,y)=-\pi$ leads again and again to the same problem. But it leads to different $\lambda$'s.

So, it's as if in one of the methods the constrain was $g(x,y)=k$ and in the other one it was $-g(x,y)=-k$. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

If you compute $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial\lambda}$ for both definition of $F$ and set them equal to zero, you'll see that they are *equivalent*. As Nick has just suggested, they both give the same optimal solutions.

*However,* $\lambda$ has other interpretations in other subjects. For instance in Economics, I'll suggest you use $F(x,y,\lambda)= f(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y)$ as a definition for Lagrangian. Why? One example is that $\lambda$ is the [Shadow price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_price). You've to "make" $\lambda$ "positive" to conclude something else. If this is the case, just bare in mind that mathematically, they give the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

They're equivalent.  You'll get different values of $\lambda$ (positive for one, negative for the other) but the same solutions in terms of $x$, $y$, and your objective function.

Answer (score 2):

In the Lagrange Multipliers technique one is searching the sattionary points which are the points such that

$$
\nabla f + \lambda \nabla g = 0
$$

which means the points such that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are linearly dependent so it is irrelevant the condition $\pm\lambda$

Answer (score 1):

If you think about what the method of Lagrange multipliers really does, you will realize it doesn't matter at all, any more than the value of $\lambda$ does.

The only thing you really care about is if the vectors
$$
u=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right), \\
v=\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x},\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)
$$
are parallel. Whether you write that as $u+\lambda v=0$ or $u-\lambda v=0$ is quite irrelevant.